# How to install openCV running from Python on OS X

Tags: macos, python, macports, opencv

**(Step 1)**

I'm trying to get openCV to run from python on my mac using the [MacPorts install](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port), and also trying to follow [The Petite Geek's guide](http://thepetitegeek.blogspot.com/2009/09/installing-opencv-on-mac-os-x-with.html):

```
sudo port -v install opencv +python26
```

It runs for about 10 minutes without errors.

**(Step 2)**

I download [ctypes-opencv source and demo files](http://code.google.com/p/ctypes-opencv/downloads/list). I navigate to the `src` directory and run:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

I see like 50 lines almost all of the form: `copying ... -> ...`, which looks good to me. No errors here.

**(Step 3)**

I add `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib` to the end of my `~/.profile`.

**(Step 4)**

I open a new terminal to test my install. From my home folder:

```
$ python

Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Apr 16 2009, 09:17:39) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5250)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
>>>
```

Does not work.

---

I read [somewhere](http://www.dudek.org/blog/150) that opencv installs python bindings with the default version of python for OSX, and I am probably running a non-default version, but this is not actionable information to me.